# How to color the arrow head in \tkzMarkAngle in the same color as the arc representing the angle?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tkz-euclide

When working on a picture using `tikz` and `tkz-euclide`, I observed that changing the color of the oriented arc representing the angle to the same color of the two segments forming this angle didn't affect the color of the arrow head. However, when coloring the arc in a different color things work perfectly.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}                                
\usetkzobj{all}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   % Defining points
      \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
      \tkzDefPoint(3,0){P}
      \tkzDefPoint(3,2){M}

      \draw[magenta] (0,0) node[anchor=north east] {$O$};      
   % Drawing the segments
      \draw[color=magenta,->,>=stealth] (0,0) -- (3,2) node[above right] {$M$};
      \draw[color=magenta,->,>=stealth] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[below] at (3,0) {$P$};
   % Marking the angle
      \tkzMarkAngle[size=1.5, draw=magenta, arrows=->,>=stealth](P,O,M)  
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Arrow Head Color problem]

How to correct this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the same color of arc and its arrow you need to change definition of color in a `tkzMarkAngle` as follows:

```
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1.5,color=magenta, arrows=-stealth](P,O,M)
```

With this modification you get:

[image]

Slightly modified (simplified) MWE for above image is:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\usetkzobj{all}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
% Defining points
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
\tkzDefPoint(3,0){P}
\tkzDefPoint(3,2){M}
% Drawing the segments
\draw[magenta,->] (0,0) node[anchor=north east] {$O$}
                        -- (3,2) node[above right] {$M$};
\draw[magenta,->] (0,0) -- (3,0) node[below]       {$P$};
% Marking the angle
\tkzMarkAngle[size=1.5,color=magenta, arrows=->](P,O,M)
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```